# Force read_csv fails when missing one header

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following csv:

```
A,B
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

on which i'm running 
`pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=',', index_col=False)`

This gives me the following dataframe, ignoring the last column:

```
A,B
1,2
4,5
```

What I want instead is pandas **to fail** (i.e throw an Index error or parser error) because the csv is not properly formatted (missing one header).

PS: running the same line with the data frame

```
A
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

will fail as I want it to (throwing an Index error).

Comment: What should be expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit header values by parameters `header=None` and `skiprows=1`:

```
temp=u"""A,B
1,2,3
4,5,6"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=None, skiprows=1)
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

If also want replace only not exist values:

```
c = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), nrows=0).columns.tolist()
df.columns = c + df.columns[len(c):].tolist()
print (df)
   A  B  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

EDIT:

```
temp=u"""A,B
1,2,3
4,5,6"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=None, skiprows=1, nrows=1)
#print (df)

c = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), nrows=0).columns.tolist()
if len(c) != len(df.columns):
    raise ValueError("The number of columns in header is different thant the number of lines")
else:
    df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp))
    print (df)
```

Another solution by commnet of @Lawis:

```
with open('data.csv') as f:
    header = next(f).count(',')
    firstrow = next(f).count(',')
    f.seek(0)

    if header != firstrow:
        raise ValueError("The number of columns in header is 
                           different thant the number of lines")
    else:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        print (df)
```

Comment: I guess my question was not entirely clear, what i would want read_csv to fail, as the csv file is not properly formatted, i will edit the question

Comment: Do you think [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#handling-bad-lines) ?

Comment: Yes exactly like this but I can't find a way to make it fail when there is n-1 columns for header and n columns for all the other lines

Comment: @Cendre - hmmm, pandas by default not support it, so this answer working in this situtation. Or not for your data?

Comment: actually the use case is the csv is a user input and I would like to fail gracefully if the csv looks like this.

Comment: @Cendre - it working nice, because `df.columns = c + df.columns[len(c):].tolist()` assign all columns from `c` to empty list with `df.columns[len(c):].tolist()`

Comment: I know your solution works. What I want is that if the user accidentally deleted a header, the read_csv will not fail. And it could cause issue, using your answer could mix up columns

Comment: @Cendre - hmmmm, it is hard, because is necessary distinguish between first row of data and first row of header.

Comment: We know that the header exists

Comment: It seems not understand each other. What is expected output if `A,B` columns?

Comment: The expected output is a failure with a message like ("The number of columns in header is different thant the number of lines" )

Comment: @Cendre Maybe you could count the number of commas in the first line (header) and compare it to the number of commas of the second line. If there is a difference, just raise an exception.